# Why do I need telegraf when creating a telegram bot?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegraf

Why do I need [telegraf](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/telegraf/) when creating a telegram bot?

I am new to creating bots and new to [telegraf](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/telegraf/) too. Do I need telegraf to listen to bot commands? And how does telegraf help?

I am just trying to understand what telegraf does in the context of the running of a telegram bot.

Answer (score 0):

I have just seen that there is [telegraf](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/telegraf/) and there is [telegraf.js](https://telegrafjs.org/#/). And this two are very different.

I was confused as I thought [telegraf](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/telegraf/) is what I had seen being used in some telegram bot code. But it was [telegraf.js](https://telegrafjs.org/#/).